# Can I retrieve the object properties after deleting the object in my asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following DeletePOST action method:-

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var lb = repository.GetLabTest(id, false);

                repository.DeleteLabTest(lb);
                repository.Save();
                return Json(new { IsSuccess = "True", id = id, description = lb.Description }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
//code goes here....
```

When I wrote the code, I thought that it will return an error on the `description = lb.Description`,, since I am deleting the `lb` object and then I am retrieving its `lb.Description` property value inside the `return Json`. But the code was able to retrieve the `Description` value for the object that was just deleted. So how does this happen?
BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That IMO is because you deleted the object from the database not the memory, a copy of that object still resides in the mem in the form of `var lb`, if you do

```
repository.Save();
lb=null;
```

then your code will throw an exception, probably, object reference not set of the sort